# RuntimeException: ActivityThread.handleSleeping

Tags: android

This crash occured on Samsung Galaxy S8+ (Android 8.0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping (ActivityThread.java:4403)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1893)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Did you have this kind of crash? Have you got some explanations?

Comment: There is no link @SantanuSur with my crash...

Comment: I'm using 27.0.2 currently.

Comment: can you post more of the crash logs, like the error message.

Comment: @RahulKumar I have no more trace unfortunately from Playstore console

Comment: I got this also - same device (bl**dy samsung)

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I am facing this issue with Samsung Galaxy S9+ (star2qltecs), Android 9

Comment: Strangely I have the same exact crash on the same Device S8+, with the same message coming from the playstore console .

Comment: Even I encountered the same issue in Galaxy S10 and Galaxy S9+ as per Playconsole Vitals.

Comment: Are you folks also seeing "android.os.TransactionTooLargeException"? I have a theory that Samsung are actually mis-reporting an error causes by saving too much information in onSavedInstance()

Comment: @Graeme Now i m seeing "android.os.TransactionTooLargeException" on samsung devices only. U have any fix for this issue.

Comment: Take a look at the TransactionTooLarge exceptions - they should point out where you're parcelling data that's too large - if onStop() once of your Fragments / Activities is bundling too much in onSavedInstanceState()

Comment: it's difficult to have an answer if you don't post any piece of source code that can help

Comment: Nearly 2 years later, on a S10, got one report of such issue. No identifiable code, so it's hard to tell what's going on and if there's any fix for this.

Comment: Me too got same crash log on play console. Device: Samsung Galaxy Note10+ (d2q), 11520MB RAM, Android 10.

Comment: It is still happening in 2022; Samsung Galaxy J6+, Android 9 (SDK 28).

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be a Samsung Specific Issue. People are facing similar crashes. A thread has been opened on [Samsung Forum](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=365613&listLines=20&startId=zzzzz~&curPage=2&searchType=ALL&searchText=hand) mentioning the exact same issue. Currently, no workaround is available as it is unknown why it's happening. Keep an eye on the thread, Samsung may come up with a workaround on that thread.

My guess is it is happening due to their Battery Saving Strategy.

Comment: Any news about this? I see this issue even on Android 10 devices. I think it's indeed more (or only) from Samsung.

Comment: @androiddeveloper no, My app still experience this crash. Almost 90% of crashes are observed on Samsung devices.

Comment: Samsung knows about this, at least? I couldn't see the thread you've linked to... It talks about deadSystemException too, right?

Comment: It is still happening, in my case with Samsung Galaxy A30 with Android 10.

Comment: @LucianoBrum I faced the exact same issue for my app in exact same phone. Do you have a workaround?